# Best practice for email links that will set a DB flag?

Tags: html, rest, api, http, email

Our business wants to email our customers a survey after they work with support. For internal reasons, we want to ask them the first question in the body of the email. We'd like to have a link for each answer. The link will go to a web service, which will store the answer, then present the rest of the survey.

So far so good.

The challenge I'm running into: making a server-side changed based on an HTTP GET is bad practice, but you can't do a POST from a link. Options seem to be:

- Use an HTTP GET instead, even though that's not correct and could cause problems (https://twitter.com/rombulow/status/990684453734203392)
- Embed an HTML form in the email and style some buttons to look like links (likely not compatible with a number of email platforms)
- Don't include the first question in the email (not possible for business reasons)
- Use HTTP GET, but have some sort of mechanism which prevents a link from altering the server state more than once

Does anybody have any better recommendations? Googling hasn't turned up much about this specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that HTTP is specifying semantics, not implementation.  If you want to change the state of your server on receipt of a GET request, you *can*.  See [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> This definition of safe methods does not prevent an implementation from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe method.  What is important, however, is that the client did not request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for it.  For example, most servers append request information to access log files at the completion of every response, regardless of the method, and that is considered safe even though the log storage might become full and crash the server.  Likewise, a safe request initiated by selecting an advertisement on the Web will often have the side effect of charging an advertising account.

Domain agnostic clients are going to assume that GET is safe, which means your survey results could get distorted by web spiders crawling the links, browsers pre-loading resource to reduce the perceived latency, and so on.

Another possibility that works in some cases is to treat the path through the graph as the resource.  Each answer link acts like a breadcrumb trail, encoding into itself the history of the clients answers.  So a client that answered A and B to the first two questions is looking at `/survey/questions/questionThree?AB` where the user that answered C to both is looking at `/survey/questions/questionThree?CC`.  In other words, you aren't changing the state of the server, you are just guiding the client through a pre-generated survey graph.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your last suggestion is a great one, except that part of the business requirement for this is that we not only present the first question in the email, but also store the answer immediately on link click. As for the HTTP specs, it's definitely true that changing a server-side resource on an HTTP GET is allowable, but it's undesirable for all the reasons you mentioned. What about when somebody's browser pre-loads both links? What about if somebody clicks one several times and Chrome pre-loads the page as part of their favorites every time they open a new tab? Etc.